# Google is un-defined while rendering Google Map in react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

Currently I'm trying to render simple map in react. Everything I've tried but all is vein. Now I've used google-maps-react for rendering google map and include its libraries but I'm still getting google is undefined I don't know why. Here is my code

```
// External Dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap , GoogleMapLoader,Marker} from 'react-google-maps';

// Internal Dependencies
import './style.css';


class HelloWorld extends Component {

  static slug = 'nel_hello_world';

  render() {
    var google = window.google;
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
       <GoogleMap
         defaultCenter = { { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 } }
         defaultZoom = { 13 }
       >
       </GoogleMap>
    ));

    // const Content = this.props.content;
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '500px' }} /> }
          mapElement={ <div style={{ height: `100%` }} /> }
        />
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Any Suggestions ?  ? ?